# Pairing and unpairing Tk CheckButtons using linked variables

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, pairing

I need to pair and unpair CheckButtons in a GUI I'm working on. That is, make them have the same state when one is pressed, or make them independent. I'm trying to accomplish this by changing the linked variable (not the value but the variable itself) of the CheckButton as illustrated in the following minimal example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
v0=Tk()
bv_c1= [IntVar(value=1), IntVar(value=1)]
#bv_c1[0]=bv_c1[1]

btn_c1=[]
for i in range(2):
    a=ttk.Checkbutton(v0, variable=bv_c1[i])
    btn_c1.append(a)
    a.grid(row=1, column=i, padx=16, pady=16)

#bv_c1[0]=bv_c1[1]
v0.mainloop()
```

The intent of the commented lines is to make both button's variables to point to the same memory address (whatever it is) and thus pairing both CheckButtons. When I uncomment the first one it works as expected: the state of the buttons remain paired when any of them is pressed. But when I uncomment the second commented line (and comment the first one) buttons remain unpaired (and one of them starts in the 'indeterminate' state). As I need to pair/unpair them depending on the environment I need to make the changes *after* button's definition, which is the situation when uncommenting the second commented line.

My question is: how would I be able to pair/unpair the buttons, and if possible, what am I doing wrong.

Additionally: my plan to unpairing back the buttons was to reconstruct the array of BooleanVars (or IntVars, tried both) bv_c1[] by executing a line similar to line 5 above, which seems to NOT work either. Perhaps due to the same misconception of mine?

EDIT:
According to TheLizzard's correct answer (thank you!), I elaborate the following working code just in case it may help someone. Lower CheckButtons are paired or not depending on the value chosen in the upper one (I know globals and the button could be avoided, but it just shows the functionality).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def done():
    global btn_c1, bv_c1
    if bv_c0[0].get():  # couple
        btn_c1[0].config(variable=bv_c1[1])
    else:               # uncouple
        btn_c1[0].config(variable=bv_c1[0])

v0=Tk()

bv_c0=[BooleanVar(value=True)]
btn_c0= ttk.Checkbutton(v0, variable=bv_c0[0])
btn_c0.grid(row=0, column=0)

ttk.Button(v0, text='done', command=done).grid(row=0, column=1)

bv_c1= [BooleanVar(value=True), BooleanVar(value=True)]
btn_c1=[]
for i in range(2):
    a=ttk.Checkbutton(v0, variable=bv_c1[i])
    btn_c1.append(a)
    a.grid(row=1, column=i, padx=6)

v0.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `<ttk.Checkbutton>.config(variable=<new variable>)`. To change the variable that the `Checkbutton` is attached to.

Comment: Can't you give the same `value` for `checkbutton`? So that, they will be paired

Comment: @PCM The problem is OP doesn't know how to unpair them. That is why I suggested OP to use the `.config` method to change the variable associated with the `Checkbutton`'s value

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks :)

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks, it worked! I should have considered that. Upvoted :-)